# Province/State invisible in Province Dropdown after upgrading to 5.5.1?

Tags: addresses

I see some of the state(province) fields have disappeared after upgrading to 5.5.1

I checked civicrm_state_province table and it has Arizona as state value but when I view a contact which earlier had Arizona state field selected does not have it now.
Other Address fields are visible but Province fields(state) are not visible.
What should be my process of debugging the issue further?

Comment: Are you talking about state field on address section on contact view page? I am not able to replicate on version 5.5.2 I can see Arizona option.

Comment: Can you share some screenshot?